# In Ruby, Whether I should treat a big file (made up of 4 characters) as Text or Binary?

Tags: ruby, text, binary

I'm now going to manipulate large files in Ruby.

What I'm going to do is to add a header line to a gigabyte size file containing a sequence of characters with no new-lines and output the result to a new file. (shown below in example). There can be one of four characters at each position in the sequence (a, c, g, t)

My questions are

1. Should I open gigabyte size file & ouput file whether as Binary or as Text file?
2. I'd like to know a sample code. (If possible, I don't want to load all the data of giga-byte size file at once on memory of my computer.)

Thanks.

---

Example
Suppose the program name is add-header-giga (The 1st argument is header-line and the 2nd argument specifies the input file name. Output file name is output-file)

```
>cat giga-byte-size-file.txt
cctgcaggagcagagcaaagaggtggccatccgcatctttcgggctgccagtttcgctcctggaggctgtgcag....


>add-header-giga DNA-sequence-from-Homo-Sapiens  giga-byte-size-file.txt


>cat output-file
DNA-sequence-from-Homo-Sapiens
cctgcaggagcagagcaaagaggtggccatccgcatctttcgggctgccagtttcgctcctggaggctgtgcag....
```

Comment: I don't get what is in the input file and what should be in the output file... The only difference I see is the `(giga-byte size file)` in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no newlines then it doesn't matter. Binary vs text only differs in their treatment of newlines.

Comment: OK, I understood. I was confused about the difference between text and binary. In this case without newline, there are no differences. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the job :

```
# Here you should check if you arguments are valid first

header = "#{ARGV[0]}\n"
file_to_read = ARGV[1]
file = IO.read(file_to_read)
open(file_to_read, 'w') { |f| f << header << file}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
....

outf = File.open("tagged_file.out", "w")
outf.write(hdr)

CHUNK = 65536
File.open(file_to_read, "r") do |inf|
    while buf = inf.read(CHUNK)
      outf.write(buf)
    end
end
```

Comment: This buffered version is very useful for me. Thanks.